# Consider $(X, d)$ a metric space and $A$ a subset of $X$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider $(X, d)$ a metric space and A a subset of $X$. Show that $(X-A)\cup int(A) $ is dense.

I'm trying to prove that the closure of $(X-A)\cup int(A)$ is X . It's clear that $\overline{(X-A)\cup int(A)} \subset X$. But how can I conclude the another inclusion?

Comment: Typically $A^\circ$ denotes the interior. Just a notational remark.

Comment: $\overline{X\setminus A}=X\setminus \textrm{int }A$

Answer (score 2):

One has $$\overline{(X-A)\cup int(A)} = \overline{X-A}\cup \overline{int(A)} = (X-int(A))\cup \overline{int(A)} = X$$

since $int(A) \subset \overline{int(A)}$.

Comment: Could you explain me why $(X-int(A)) \cup \overline{int(A)} =X$?

Comment: Because $int(A) \subset \overline{int(A)}$ ! You are "substracting" to $X$ the subset $int(A)$, and then "adding" a larger subset ($\overline{int(A)}$)...